# Why is it taking 10 inputs?

Tags: c

Who does the following program take 10 inputs instead of 9?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[3][3];

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
            scanf("%d ", &arr[j][i]);


    printf("\n");

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
            printf("\n%d ", arr[j][i]);
    

     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A space character in a format string tells `scanf` to read and discard white space characters (including spaces, tabs, and new-line characters) until a non-white-space character (or end of stream or error) is seen. So, after reading a number, `scanf("%d ")` continues reading. If you pressed Enter/Return after entering a number, `scanf` reads the new-line character that generated. Then it reads the next character. Only when you enter a non-white-space character, such as a digit, does it stop.

Remove the space from the `scanf` string. `%d` already includes reading and ignoring white-space characters before the number, so another space is not needed in the string.

Comment: Actually the space should be before the %d to discard leading whitespace.

Comment: @AlexNicolaou: No, it should not. Leading white-space characters are already discarded, per C 2018 7.21.6.2 8, which discusses the first step of execution a conversion specification (a `scanf` directive starting with `%`): “Input white-space characters (as specified by the `isspace` function) are skipped, unless the specification includes a `[`, `c`, or `n` specifier.”

Comment: You're right, I was thinking of `%c`.